# Laravel 4 Static Facades Setup in Packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm playing around with packages and I'm able to my code to work (in my controllers) when I do this:

```
App::make('Assets')->js('bla');
```

Now I want to set up a static facade so I can do this:

```
Assets::js('bla');
```

for this and I'm getting errors.  I've been following [this blog entry](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench) and haven't had any trouble up to this point.  But now I'm stuck with a " Call to undefined method" error.

I'm not sure what code you'd need to see, so here's everything: https://github.com/JoeCianflone/msl/tree/jc-working

Specifically here is my workbench: https://github.com/JoeCianflone/msl/tree/jc-working/workbench/Joecianflone/Assets

And here is the controller where I was messing around with it: https://github.com/JoeCianflone/msl/blob/jc-working/app/controllers/HomeController.php

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with namespacing, I got it working by changing this:

```
<?php namespace Joecianflone\Assets\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Assets extends Facade {

/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'Assets'; }

}
```

to this:

```
class Assets extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade {

/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'Joecianflone\Assets\Assets'; }

}
```

What I'm not sure about is why the code from the tutorial worked but mine didn't.  I must have skipped a step.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sidenote, if you plan to share your code with the communuty (please do) i encourage you to use 5.3 syntax. Laravel requirements is 5.3 so dont use 5.4 in your package.

Comment: I agree 100% with that, this code was really just me learning workbench.  eventually I wanted to play with other 5.4 features in here too, but I need to get past this one hump.

Comment: Great! Ill check your package when i get to a computer ;)